# Detour Identifier not found

Tags: c++, dll, detours

I'm getting the error

```
error C3861: 'DetourTransactionBegin': identifier not found
error C3861: 'DetourUpdateThread': identifier not found
error C3861: 'DetourAttach': identifier not found
error C3861: 'DetourAttach': identifier not found
error C3861: 'DetourAttach': identifier not found
error C3861: 'DetourAttach': identifier not found
error C3861: 'DetourTransactionCommit': identifier not found
error C3861: 'DetourTransactionBegin': identifier not found
error C3861: 'DetourUpdateThread': identifier not found
error C3861: 'DetourDetach': identifier not found
error C3861: 'DetourDetach': identifier not found
error C3861: 'DetourDetach': identifier not found
error C3861: 'DetourDetach': identifier not found
error C3861: 'DetourTransactionCommit': identifier not found
```

Code with the error:

```
DetourTransactionBegin();
DetourUpdateThread( GetCurrentThread() );
DetourAttach( &(PVOID &)Real_Send, Mine_Send );
DetourAttach( &(PVOID &)Real_Recv, Mine_Recv );
DetourAttach( &(PVOID &)Real_RecvFrom, Mine_RecvFrom );
DetourAttach( &(PVOID &)Real_WSARecvEx, Mine_WSARecvEx );
DetourTransactionCommit();
```

My complete header file:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <detours.h>

#pragma comment( lib, "Ws2_32.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "detours.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "detoured.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "Mswsock.lib" )
```

And I just cant find the problem.
I added the dir of detours.lib on the additional includes on the linker options.

using detours 1.5

---

**UPDATE**

So I tried adding the detours files locally to the project.

```
#include "detours.h"
```

Still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These functions are in detours 2.1 API.

Comment: One last questions though, fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'detoured.lib' ?

Comment: Looks like it is debug version of the library.

Comment: I guess that when you build in debug configuration it requires detoured.lib. 'd' basically means that it is debug version of the library. But this is just guess. You may want to check what happens if you build your project in release configuration.